# How to bind from outside a tab control into a tab control when using ControlTemplates?

Tags: wpf

I want to bind from outside a tab control to its inside. It works as long in principle but when I use a ContentTemplate I have no clue how to address the binding target.

The code below has two pairs of TextBlock and TabItem. The first block works, the second, using  a ContentTemplate doesn't.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    
    <TextBlock 
        Grid.Row="0"
        Text="{Binding ElementName=redTtextBlock, Path=Text}" 
        Foreground="Red"
        />

    <TabControl Grid.Row="1">
        <TabItem 
            Header="Red header"
            >
            <TextBlock 
                    x:Name="redTtextBlock"
                    Text="Red text"
                    Foreground="Red"
                    />
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
    
    <TextBlock 
        Grid.Row="2"
        Text="{Binding ElementName=greenTtextBlock, Path=Text}" 
        Foreground="Olive"
        />

    <TabControl Grid.Row="3">
        <TabControl.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="template" DataType="TabItem">
                <TextBlock 
                    x:Name="greenTtextBlock"
                    Text="Green text"
                    Foreground="Olive"
                    />
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.Resources>
            <TabItem 
                Header="Green header"
                ContentTemplate="{StaticResource template}">
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>

</Grid>
```

Comment: You cannot bind to the actual `TextBlock` created by the `DataTemplate`. You should bind both `TextBlocks` to a common source property.

Comment: Thank you mm8. Good option to circumvent that limitation. 
But may I ask this; How could I have known? Is there an explanation when one can bind to elements together and when not? It comes to me as a surprise that this binding is not possible directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can never bind from outside of any template to its inside. This are totally different scopes.

> "How could I have known? Is there an explanation when one can bind to elements together and when not? It comes to me as a surprise that this binding is not possible directly."

You shouldn't be surprised. If you understand how templates work, then you would know that the second binding can't work.
The first example binds to a control where binding target and source share a common namescope. A template e.g., `DataTemplate` or `ControlTemplate` has always it's own namescope, as it describes a dynamic visual subtree.

Think about it: a `DataTemplate`, that is defined as the item template of a `ItemsControl` and contains an element named "TemplateElement" is applied to every item of this `ItemsControl`.
If the template wouldn't define its own isolated namescope, then there would be multiple elements of the same name - in the same namescope. Pretending that this is legal, how can the binding expression "know" which of the duplicate elements the binding uses as its source? They are duplicates from the naming point of view but unique regarding their content. This should make it clear that it can never work.

The `DataTemplate` is not the item. It's the construction blueprint for multiple items. Because of this multiplicity, it is not possible to bind from outside of the template to an element of this template. Same applies to the `ControlTemplate`.

Furthermore and most important, templates are part of the visual tree but not the logical tree. Beside the namescope in case of `Binding.ElementName`, this is the main reason why a `Binding` defined outside a template cannot resolve the source, if the source itself is part of a template. `Binding.RelativeSource` expressions only traverse the logical tree. This means a `Binding` can never find a composed element's internals (visual tree), but only the direct top-level elements (logical tree).

Comment: Thanks a lot BioncCode. I learned a lot!
Somehow the TabControl is special though, if I remember correctly, in that it has only one visual tree for all items, isn't it?

Comment: `TabControl`is a hybrid of `ItemsControl` and `ContentControl`. It has items, the `TabItem` elements. A `TabItem` has a header, the `TabItem.Content`, which is templated via the `TabControl.ItemTemplate`. All headers are always visible. And `TabItem`  has content, the `TabControl.SelectedContent`, which is templated via the `TabControl.ContentTemplate`. Only one content is visible, the content of `TabControl.SelectedItem`.

Comment: All tab items share a single content host, which displays the actual content of the currently selected `TabItem`, the value of `TabControl.SelectedContent`. As you can see from the property qualifier, the content host is not part of the `TabItem`, but part of the `TabControl` itself. This means while each item has its own visual (sub)tree to describe their headers, there is only a single visual (sub)tree that describes the content. Each tab's contennt  is swapped in and out.

Comment: Cool. Thanks again.